# Crontabs / Cron Jobs Not Able to Edit or Create File

Tags: cron

I try to edit the crontab file to create conjobs by using ssh `sudo crontab -e` and `crontab -e`, but I keep getting the following error message (or as shown in the image below):

```
no crontab for root - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.C7Hy04/crontab":22: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

[image: sudo crontab -e]

And the file path location `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` folder is empty. Shouldn't there be a cron file of some type to edit?

So what I'm trying to do is create cron jobs to handle my Mautic cron tasks/jobs as shown below:

```
php /var/www/aaronsnewsletters.com/public_html/bin/console mautic:segments:update
php /var/www/aaronsnewsletters.com/public_html/bin/console mautic:campaigns:update
php /var/www/aaronsnewsletters.com/public_html/bin/console mautic:campaigns:trigger
php /var/www/aaronsnewsletters.com/public_html/bin/console mautic:iplookup:download
php /var/www/aaronsnewsletters.com/public_html/bin/console mautic:broadcasts:send
php /var/www/aaronsnewsletters.com/public_html/bin/console mautic:maintenance:cleanup --days-old=60 --no-interaction
```

Do I need to somehow reinstall the crontab setup or how do I get back to being able to edit with nano? At this point, I'm not able to edit the main crontab file & nor do I know where it is located.

Thanks for any support.

Comment: That's not a *system* error. That's the system saying that YOU made an error, and rejecting the crontab for that reason. You don't need to reinstall or fix anything -- there is likely nothing wrong with your system.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: @user535733 then where do I set those cron jobs for Mautic that I've listed above? I dont see that they are being set anywhere. How do I confirm that they've indeed been set?

Comment: @AaronEsteban what do you mean exactly by "those cron jobs"? The php commands that you posted are just that - commands, not cron jobs. In particular each one needs to be preceded by a valid cron timespec

Comment: Since the crontab application rejected the cronjobs (and told you why), you can be reasonably certain that those jobs have NOT been set. Oh, and NEVER try to edit anything in /var/spool. That will always end badly. Use the `crontab` command to create/edit a crontab just like the rest of us do.